Probability of selecting less than 4 unique numbers from a list of 21 in 10 samples with replacement
I have a list of 21 numbers, numbered 0 to 20 (or 1 to 21, it doesn't matter). I make 10 random picks, each time making the pick available for the next pick. What is the probability that the 10 picks have less than 4 unique numbers?
I approached the combinatorics problem with a formula that I thought was correct, but when I simulated the process on a spreadsheet I obtained a very different result: What is the correct formula please? Below are my explanation for how I obtained the formula, and the simulation result.
The probability of picking less than 4 unique numbers is the probability of picking always the same number + the probability of picking 2 different numbers + the probability of picking 3 different numbers.
$$P(<4) = P(1) + P(2) +P(3)$$
On my first pick of 10 I obtain 1 unique number. On my 2nd pick I could either pick the same with probability $\frac1{21}$, or pick a different number with probability $\frac{20}{21}$. The probability of always picking the same number in the 9 picks after the first will be
$$P(1) = \left(\frac1{21}\right)^9$$
After the 2nd pick, in which I picked a number different than the first one, I have a 3rd pick, in which I could either pick one of the previous 2 numbers with probability $\frac2{21}$, or pick a 3rd different number with probability $\frac{19}{21}$. The probability that I continue to pick the same 2 numbers in the remaining 8 picks after the first 2 will be
$(\frac{2}{21})^8$, therefore
$$P(2) = \frac{20}{21}\left(\frac{2}{21}\right)^8$$
Continuing the same line of thought, on the 4th pick I could either pick one of the previously picked 3 numbers with probability $\frac3{21}$, or pick a 4th different number with probability $\frac{18}{21}$. The probability that I continue to pick the same 3 numbers in the remaining 7 picks after the first 3 will be
$(\frac{3}{21})^7$, therefore
$$P(3) = \frac{20}{21}\frac{19}{21}\left(\frac3{21}\right)^7$$
Summing the three terms up
$$P(<4) = \left(\frac1{21}\right)^9 + \frac{20}{21}\left[\left(\frac{2}{21}\right)^8 + \frac{19}{21}\left(\frac3{21}\right)^7\right] = $$
which gives me approximately $P(<4) = 0.00011\%$
When I try to verify the result by simulating the process in Google sheets, I am not able to simulate enough trials for the calculation; the probability above means an average of 1 for approximately 909,000 trials, but I found out that Google sheets allows me to simulate approximately 47,500 trials. Therefore I downsized the problem from 10 picks to 8 picks, obtaining by induction
$$P(<4) = \left(\frac1{21}\right)^7 + \frac{20}{21}\left[\left(\frac{2}{21}\right)^6 + \frac{19}{21}\left(\frac3{21}\right)^5\right] = 0.0052\%$$
But when I simulate it I obtain $P(<4) = 0.016\%$
The Google Sheets formula I use to simulate the above result is
=countif( byrow( map(RANDarray(55000, 8), lambda(x, int(x*21))), lambda(trial,COUNTUNIQUE(trial)) ), "<4") / 55000


For the situations where you have two or three different numbers, you considered cases where the second pick is different from the first pick, but that is not neccesarily the case. You can have for example 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, which are two different numbers but the first two picks the same.

@SextusEmpiricus, but wouldn't your example be covered by the probability that both the 2nd and the 3rd number have a 2/21 probability of being either 1 or 2? What formula do you suggest please?

ok take this example 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2

This question sounds like a textbook exercise. What is the purpose of the exercise in this question? What is it that you need to learn?

btw using a Markov chain computation I get $$1- \frac{794276490960}{21^9} \approx 4.48 \cdot 10^{-6}$$

The easiest way to obtain the answer might be to apply the recurrence relation for the chance of drawing exactly $k$ unique values out of $N=20$ distinct values after $n=10$ draws and summing these probabilities for $k=0,1,\ldots 3.$

@SextusEmpiricus, as I wrote there must be a flaw in my line of reasoning. The question comes from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78610275/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-google-sheets, in which two different methods are proposed to generate a series of 4 unique numbers. I'm trying to compare the probability that it doesn't work correctly. Could you please use your Markov chain computation for the case with 8 picks? I'd like to compare it to my Monte Carlo.

@whuber I was trying to do something similar in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78610275/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-google-sheets post I wrote, but the result didn't convince me. What's the case for k=0 anyway?

You need a place to start your recurrence and you can do that by noting the chance of $k=0$ is zero whenever $n\gt 0.$

@whuber if you are interested I posted a recursive formula.

This is the classical occupancy problem (use the occupancy package)
Your question is a particular case of the "classical occupancy problem" which leads to the classical occupancy distribution (see e.g., O'Neill 2021).  Suppose you take a sample of size $n$ from a set of $m$ distinct numbers, using simple-random-sampling with replacement, and let $K$ be the number of distinct numbers you sample.  This random variable follows the classical occupancy distribution with probability mass function:
$$\mathbb{P}(K=k|n,m) = \text{Occ}(k|n,m) = \frac{(m)_k \cdot S(n,k)}{m^n}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 1 \leqslant k \leqslant \min(n,m),$$
where $(m)_k = m(m-1)(m-2) \cdots (m-k+1)$ are the falling factorials and $S(n,k)$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind.  The properties of this distribution and various extension distributions have been examined in quite a bit of detail (see e.g., O'Neill 2021, O'Neill 2023).  This probability distribution has existing facilities in R in the occupancy package.  The probability of interest to you can be obtained by calling the pocc function (which gives the CDF of the occupancy distribution):
#Load library
library(occupancy)

#Compute probability of a value less than four
pocc(x = 3, size = 10, space = 21)

[1] 4.476533e-06


Interesting that my solution, which gives results identical to the occupancy distribution you explained, is related to partition numbers. The other similar element are the falling factorials that can be obtained by simplifying the ration between the various combinations C(u,u-i)/C(n,u-i).

@gciriani: In your framing you should get $\text{Uperm}(n,p,u) = (n)_u \cdot S(p,u)$, which is the numerator of the classical occupancy mass function (see O'Neill 2021 for a combinatorial derivation of this result).

I'm not familiar with your notation, but I understand it. I guess my formula is a different way of expressing the occupancy mass function because I obtain the same results.

I just verified that my recursive formula gives the same result as $Uperm(n,p,u)=(n)_u * S(p,u)$. Thanks for suggesting to do this verification. Is it okay for me to undo the selected answer and switch to your solution? I don't want to be unfair to who verified first what the correct result was, but your solution should appear on top.

@gciriani: There is no need to remove your answer; it is a reasonable first-principles derivation (though it differs from the standard approach).  It is generally fine to have multiple different approaches in the answers and let the voting system do the rest.

Here is an example in R showing how you can compute this with simulation, a Markov chain or recursive equation, and an estimate
Markov chain
The Markov chain considers a vector with probabilities for the states after $k$ picks and computes the vector for the state after $k+1$ picks based on the previous vector.
$$x_k = \text{(1 unique, 2 unique, 3 unique, 4 or more unique)}$$
and
$$x_{k+1} = x_k \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{n-1}{n} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{2}{n} & \frac{n-2}{n} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{3}{n} & \frac{n-3}{n} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
estimate
This considers the probability that for a given exact three numbers they are the only ones to be picked which is probability $(3/21)^{10}$, and this gets multiplied with the number of ways to choose exact three numbers $n \choose 3$.
exact
The estimate counts situations double. For example the situation that we pick uniquely only the numbers 1 and 2, occurs in the situations that we pick uniquely 1,2,3 or 1,2,4, 1,2,5, etc. So the estimate counted the situations with 1 or 2 unique cases multiple times.
The idea is a bit following P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) I believe there is some more thorough description of this approach already on this website or on a wikipedia page.
             10 picks      8 picks  
Markov/Exact 4.476533e-06  0.000205
Simulation   0.000008      0.000217
Estimate     4.708377e-06  0.000231

    

code
####
#### Using a Markov chain 
####

library(matrixcalc)

n = 21
m = 10

M = matrix(data = c(1, n-1,   0 , 0,
                    0,   2, n-2 , 0,
                    0,   0,   3 , n-3,
                    0,   0,   0 , n)
           ,nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE) / n

start = c(1,0,0,0)

end = start %*% matrix.power(M, m-1)

### result 4.476533e-06 for n = 21 and m = 10
### result 0.0002052209 for n = 21 and m = 8
1-end[4]


####
#### Using a simulation 
####

sim = function() {
  x = sample(1:n,m, replace = TRUE)
  t = tabulate(x)
  full_bins = sum(t>0)
  output = (full_bins < 4)
  return(output)
}

### result 0.000008 for n = 21 and m = 10
### result 0.000217 for n = 21 and m = 8
set.seed(1)
mean(replicate(10^6,sim()))

####
#### Using an estimate 
####

### result 4.708377e-06 for n = 21 and m = 10
### result 0.0002307105 for n = 21 and m = 8
(3/n)^m * choose(n,3)

####
#### exact computation
####

### result 4.476533e-06 for n = 21 and m = 10
### result 0.0002052209 for n = 21 and m = 8

a3 =  (3/n)^m * choose(n,3)
a2 =  (2/n)^m * choose(n,2)
a1 =  (1/n)^m * choose(n,1)
b2 = a2 - (n-1) * a1
a3 - (n-2-1) * b2 - ((n-1) * (n-2)/2 - 1) * a1 


For 8 uniques, the Google Sheets simulation for 8 picks with <4 unique, shown at the end of the OP, is 0.00016 (560,000 trials). Your calc gives 0.000217. A much smaller toy example of 3 picks out of 4 numbers, with 2 or 1 unique shows the difference. There are 4^3=64 outcomes, of which 24 have 3 unique numbers, 36 have 2 unique numbers, and 4 have 1 unique number. So the probability is 40/64=0.625, whereas the combinatorics you adopted in your estimate gives (4,2) = 6 combinations with a probability (1/2)^3= 1/8, and multiplying the two the results is 0.75.

I have to amend my comment before this, but leaving that for historical tracking. My initial simulation didn't return your same numbers, due to statistical variance. Your Markov chain gives correct results; the rationale for the estimate double, triple, etc. counts a bunch of cases, and that is reflected in the higher number. I'll post a solution with the correct combinatorics, that give the exact solution.

@gciriani does my computation at the end contain an error? $$\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)^m{{n}\choose{3}} - (n-2-1) \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^m{{n}\choose{2}} - (-(n-1)(n-2)/2-2+n) \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m{{n}\choose{1}}$$

For the case of 2 or 1 unique cases this would change in $$\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^m{{n}\choose{2}} - (n-1-1) \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m{{n}\choose{1}}$$ and with $m=3$ and $n = 4$ you'd get $$\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^3 \cdot 6 - 2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 \cdot 4 = \frac{5}{8} = 0.625$$

I recognize that the structure is similar, and since you obtain the correct results it must be right. I came up with a recursive formula, because I wanted to automate it in a spreadsheet. So I calculates the case for 2 uniques based on 1 unique, then calculate the case for 3 uniques based on 2 uniques, and so on.  I will post later.

I posted the recursive formula if you are interested.

The Markov chain shown by Sextus Empiricus in his post gives correct results. However, because I also wanted to have a recursive formula based on combinatorics, I came up with the following:
The parameters of the problem are:

n number of objects (numbers), being picked with substitution;
p number of picks;
u number of unique objects after p picks.

I define the following combinatorial notation:
$$Uperm(n,p,u)$$ as the number of permutations obtained from p picks, with replacement, selected from a collection of n different ones, of which u are unique. By analyzing the combinatorial relationships between $Uperm(n,p,u)$ and $Uperm(n,p,u+1)$, I obtained the following recursive formula:
$$\begin{align}
Uperm(n,p,u)= C(n,u)\;\cdot [ u^p  &- Uperm(n,p,u-1)\cdot\frac{C(u,u-1)}{C(n,u-1)}\\
&- Uperm(n,p,u-2)\cdot\frac{C(u,u-2)}{C(n,u-2)}\\
& \vdots\\
&- Uperm(n,p,1)\cdot\frac{C(u,1)}{C(n,1)} ]
\end{align}$$
Where $C(x,y)=\binom{x}{y}$ are the combinations of x objects taken y at a time.
The recursive solution can be simplified with a summation:
$$Uperm(n,p,u)= C(n,u)\;\cdot \left[ u^p  - \sum_{i=1}^{u-1}Uperm(n,p,i)\cdot\frac{C(u,i)}{C(n,i)}\right]$$
It must be noted that the fraction of the two combinations can be further simplified into falling factorials:
$$\frac{C(u,i)}{C(n,i)}=\frac{u(u-1)\dots(u-i+1)}{n(n-1)\dots(n-i+1)}$$
However, I left on purpose the combinatorial formula, because in Google Sheets, which is the calculation tool I used, combinatorial functions are available, falling factorial formulas are longer to write.
For the toy example with n=4 and p=3, which can be manually checked by inspection, Uperm(4,3,3)=24, Uperm(4,3,2)=36, and Uperm(4,3,1)=4, out of a total of $n^p=4^3=64$ cases.
For the more advanced test example with n=21, p=8, and u=1...3, one obtains.
$$\begin{align}
Uperm(21,8,1) &=21\\
Uperm(21,8,2)&=53,340\\
Uperm(21,8,3)&=7,708,680
\end{align}$$
The sum of the three is 7,762,041 and given that all possible picks for u =1...p picks are $n^p$, in our case $21^8 = 37,822,859,361$. Thus the probability of having less than 4 unique picks is $p = 7,762,041 / 37,822,859,361 = 0.000205221$
Finally for the original problem with n=21, p=10, and u=1...3, one obtains.
$$\begin{align}
Uperm(21,10,1) &=21\\
Uperm(21,10,2)&=214,620\\
Uperm(21,10,3)&=74,453,400
\end{align}$$
The sum of the three is 74,668,041 and given that all possible picks for u =1...p picks are $n^p$, in our case $21^{10} = 16,679,880,978,201$. Thus the probability of having less than 4 unique picks is $p = 74,668,041 / 16,679,880,978,201 = 0.000004476533202$
EDIT
Worth to note that, as pointed out in a comment by @Ben in the solution by him proposed, because of the recursive nature of my Uperm(n,p,u), it  eventually turns into a Sterling number, thus
$$
Uperm(n,p,u) = (n)_u \cdot S(p,u)
$$
